# Showing that a piece-wise defined sequence converges to $-\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to show that $\displaystyle S_n = \begin{cases}
  3-\sqrt{n}, & \mbox{if n is even} \\
  -\frac{\sqrt{n}}{3},  & \mbox{if n is odd } \end{cases}$ converges to $-\infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

I've tried as follows:

Let $m>0$. Take $N =\lceil (3-m)^2\rceil+1$. Then $n > N$ gives:

$n > (3-m)^2 \implies \sqrt{n} >3-m \implies -\sqrt{n} < m-3  \implies 3-\sqrt{n} <m$ if $n$ is even

$\displaystyle n > (3-m)^2 \implies \sqrt{n} >3-m < -\frac{\sqrt{n}}{3} < m/3-1  \implies 3-\sqrt{n} <m$ if $n$ is odd.

Does this work?

<strike>There are several things that confuse me here. For one $-\sqrt{n}/3$ is always less than $0$, so would taking any $m>0$ suffice? Second, do I need to use absolute value sign somewhere?</strike>

Comment: Try to write down the definition of $\lim x_n = -\infty$ and you'll see that taking $m>0$ as you've done is not sufficient.

Comment: @rldias Yes, I've realised that didn't make any sense. What I perhaps wanted to ask was, since the piece of the sequence defined for even values always exceeds the piece defined for odd values, can I take the $N$ I've taken for the first bit?

Comment: By 'exceed' I think you meant $|3-\sqrt{n}| \geq | -\sqrt{n}/3|$. Since it holds, you can take $N$ such that $-\sqrt{n}/3 < -M$ for $n>N$, where $M$ is some arbitrarily fixed positive constant.